# How to detect 3 key presses in SWT KeyListener

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp

As of now i am using below code to detect two key presses. I.e, Ctrl+F(or) Shift+1...Etc,

```
 CCombo comboBox = this.cellEditor.getViewer().getCCombo();
KeyAdapter keyAdapter = new KeyAdapter()
{
  @Override
  public void keyPressed(final KeyEvent evt)
  {
  // KeyPreferenceUtils is used to get the eclipse workbench key preference values.
    int keyCode = KeyPreferenceUtils.getKeyValue();
    if ((evt.stateMask == SWT.CTRL) || (evt.stateMask == SWT.ALT) || (evt.stateMask == SWT.SHIFT) || (evt.stateMask == SWT.COMMAND))
    {
      String pressedKey = Action.convertAccelerator(evt.stateMask + evt.keyCode);
      int pressedKeyValue = Action.convertAccelerator(pressedKey);
      if (pressedKeyValue == keyCode)
      {
        comboBox.setListVisible(true);
      }
    }
    else if (evt.keyCode == keyCode)
    {
      comboBox.setListVisible(true);
    }
  }
};
comboBox.addKeyListener(keyAdapter);
```

Now my problem is i want detect 3 key presses. I.e, Ctrl+Shift+2 or some keys combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know SWT that well but I'd assume `evt.stateMask` is an `int` used to represent a bit field and the `SWT.XXX` values represent masks for the corresponding bits. Thus you could try `if (evt.stateMask & SWT.CTRL > 0 && evt.stateMask & SWT.SHIFT > 0)`.

To clarify `evt.stateMask & SWT.CTRL > 0` would mean that if the bit defined by `SWT.CTRL` is set in `stateMask` you'll get a value greater than 0 otherwise you get 0. However, if other bits are set as well you'll not detect that with that approach.

If you only want to allow those bits to be set you could try `if (evt.stateMask == (SWT.CTRL |  SWT.SHIFT) )` (i.e. you combine the two masks ans then compare).

Example:

We'll use 8-bit values for simplicity and assume `SWT.CTRL = 00000001` and `SWT.SHIFT = 00000100`.

With the first approach you'd get true for masks like `10000101`, `00010101`, `00000101` and false for masks like `00100100` etc.

With the second approach you'd only get true for `stateMask = 00000101`.

Answer (score 2):

you want to or the mask codes

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(final KeyEvent evt)
{
// KeyPreferenceUtils is used to get the eclipse workbench key preference values.
    int keyCode = KeyPreferenceUtils.getKeyValue();
    if ((evt.stateMask & (SWT.CTRL | SWT.ALT)) == (SWT.CTRL | SWT.ALT)){
       // both ctrl and alt are pressed so do something
    }
    else if ((evt.stateMask == SWT.CTRL) || (evt.stateMask == SWT.ALT) || (evt.stateMask == SWT.SHIFT) || (evt.stateMask == SWT.COMMAND))
    {
       // do something else
    }
    else if (evt.keyCode == keyCode)
    {
        comboBox.setListVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The above method hard codes the key press to 'Ctrl' / 'Alt' / 'Shift' / etc..
If the user enters any key other than this, this logic will not help me.
Is it possible to make it generic? i.e for any 3 keys entered by user to be parsed?

Comment: You could always test all the state mask flags and count how many are set.